# The body of.../...'s body

Tags: grammar

1. He looked down at Mr. Harden's body.
2. He looked down at the body of Mr. Harden.

If we by "body" means "corpse" is one of the two phrasings more natural to use than the other?

Answer (score 2):

To me these two sentences have the same meaning.

The second example, however, emphasizes the "body" part of the sentence by moving it before "Mr. Harden".  You often see this type of emphasis in literature for dramatic effect.

When speaking the first example seems more natural although talking about dead bodies is not something most people do in daily conversation.